# Linux sees only 1/2 of my RAM?

Tags: lubuntu, ram

Linux see only 1/2 of my ram
My RAM size is 2048mb, but linux see only 1300mb. Why?
No, it's not buffered, because ubuntu free command don't print free buffered RAM
Here is output of command `free`

[image]

Lubuntu 16.04 x32

Comment: Take a look at the column named "total" in the output of `free` and you'll notice that everything is as it should be.

Comment: please don't use profanity in your posts

Comment: Hm. Available column is available ram free + buffered?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/85695). Just copy the text and paste it directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to make it appear as code. plus, that image is tiny.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your RAM is there. It's just that some of it is being used. Whenever your computer is on, some things will be loaded into its RAM so you will *never* see the entire RAM shown as "available". What you are looking for is in the "total" column.

For example, on my machine:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15938        9361        2307        1436        4269        4807
Swap:         16383         868       15515
```

I have 15938 M of RAM, of which 4807 is currently available and 9361 is being used by various processes. You don't see `2048` because you're using `-m`. Try `--mega` instead. And if your next question is why is Linux taking so much RAM, see http://linuxatemyram.com.

Comment: Thanks :)
Available - is currently available + buffered?

Comment: @monobogdan basically, yes. You might want to read http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261252/22222